# iOS Distribution Certificate expiration - Ad Hoc apps

Tags: ios, certificate, distribution, adhoc

I developed an app for iPad that is being used by one person (never posted to the app store) it was delivered an ad hoc.

It's for personal, non-commercial use.  The person is getting (of course) a 'certificate expiration' warning as the cert expires in a few weeks.  Is there a way to get around that for an ad hoc app - without using using an enterprise developer account?  We only have 1 user - but its important that the app continue working for him.  Do we need to create a new cert, rebuild the app and send him a new IPA?  Any good ideas to get around this?

Comment: Short answer for: " Do we need to create a new cert, rebuild the app and send him a new IPA?" = YES!

Comment: Note that there is no way around the certificate expiration issue without using the App Store. Even if you used enterprise distribution, you'd have to renew the cert and re-upload a new IPA when it expires.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rebuild the app, just create a new IPA from your existing archive using the new certificate.

Comment: How to create the new IPA without rebuilding the app?

Answer (score -4):

I would imagine asking Apple would be a good place to start. At least you will know if you can do so legitimately before trying other work arounds 
https://developer.apple.com/contact/#technical